# Обратная анимация requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, математика, анимация

Класс анимации:

```
interface IInitAnimate {
  duration: number;
  timing: (timeFraction: number) => number;
  draw: (progress: number) => void;
}

interface IConstructor {
  onStart?: () => void;
  onProcessing?: () => void;
  onEnd?: () => void;
}

interface IEvents {
  start?: () => void;
  processing?: () => void;
  end?: () => void;
}

export class Animation {
  animationProcessing: boolean;
  requestID: number | null;
  animationStartTime: number | null;

  on: IEvents;

  duration: number | null;
  timing: ((timeFraction: number) => number) | null;
  draw: ((progress: number) => void) | null;

  constructor({ onStart, onProcessing, onEnd }: IConstructor) {
    this.animationProcessing = false;
    this.requestID = null;
    this.animationStartTime = null;

    this.on = {
      start: onStart,
      processing: onProcessing,
      end: onEnd,
    };

    this.duration = null;
    this.timing = null;
    this.draw = null;
  }

  initAnimate({ duration, timing, draw }: IInitAnimate) {
    this.duration = duration;
    this.timing = timing;
    this.draw = draw;

    this.animationProcessing && cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestID!);
    this.animationProcessing = true;
    this.animationStartTime = null;

    this.on.start && this.on.start();
    this.requestID = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  }

  animate = (time: number) => {
    if (!this.animationStartTime) this.animationStartTime = time;
    let timeFraction = (time - this.animationStartTime!) / this.duration!;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    let progress = this.timing!(timeFraction);

    this.on.processing && this.on.processing();
    this.draw!(progress);

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      this.requestID = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    } else {
      this.on.end && this.on.end();
      this.animationProcessing = false;
    }
  };
}
```

Вызов анимации:

```
animation.initAnimate({
 duration: duration,
 timing: (timeFraction) => { //return от 0 до 1
        //timeFraction = от 0 до 1
        //return 1 - Math.pow(1 - timeFraction, 2);
        //return --timeFraction * timeFraction * timeFraction + 1;
        return timeFraction < 0.5
          ? 4 * timeFraction * timeFraction * timeFraction
          : (timeFraction - 1) *
              (2 * timeFraction - 2) *
              (2 * timeFraction - 2) +
              1;
      },
 draw: (progress) => {//progress = от 0 до 1}
});
```

И вот например, я вызвал первую анимацию которая длится скажем 10 секунд, я ее прервал на 3 секунде, и того она длилась 3 секунды

Прерываю я ее вызовом `animation.initAnimate` , если была не завершена старая анимация,

на третьей секунде прогресс в методе дров = 0.108 (timing(0.3))

как ее теперь повернуть назад, чтобы она длилась 3 секунды и в метод дров приходил прогресс 0.8919999999999999 (timing(0.7))

Чтобы анимация назад выглядела естественно?

И как сделать вот такие повороты анимации каждый раз когда я ее прерываю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно всего лишь повернуть течение времени, и немного по другому считать процент отработанной анимации.

в методе animate добавить проверку на пересчет времени:

```
if (this.redefineStartTime) {
      const pastTime = time - this.animationStartTime!;
      this.animationStartTime =
        this.animationStartTime! - (this.duration! - pastTime - pastTime);
      this.redefineStartTime = false;
    }

    let timeFraction =
      Math.abs(time - this.animationStartTime!) / this.duration!;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;
```

а в методе initAnimate, проверять на активность анимации и если да, то включить пересчет времени.

```
if (this.animationProcessing) {
      this.redefineStartTime = true;
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestID!);
    }
```